# Can not get cmake to complete Ubuntu 20.4, cmake for INDI package, Below are the commands used and the link for instructions

Tags: software-installation

Installing and building the INDI software has errors. I need to solve this
anyone know what I need to do, or a different way to put INDI on Ubuntu?

Instructions on building INDI fron https://github.com/indilib/indi

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mkdir -p ~/Projects
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd Projects/
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects$ sudo git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/indilib/indi.git
Cloning into 'indi'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 742, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (742/742), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (709/709), done.
remote: Total 742 (delta 130), reused 130 (delta 18), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (742/742), 2.44 MiB | 1.87 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (130/130), done.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects$ sudo mkdir -p ~/Projects/build/indi-core
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects$ ls
build  indi
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects$ cd build/indi-core/
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects/build/indi-core$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects/build/indi-core$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Projects/build/indi-core$ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ~/Projects/indi
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test COMPATIBLE_FORTIFY_SOURCE
-- Performing Test COMPATIBLE_FORTIFY_SOURCE - Success
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found CFITSIO 3.47: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcfitsio.so
-- Found CFITSIO: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcfitsio.so
-- Found NOVA: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnova.so
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Found USB1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so (found version "1.0.23") 
-- Performing Test USB1_HAS_LIBUSB_ERROR_NAME
-- Performing Test USB1_HAS_LIBUSB_ERROR_NAME - Success
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so (found version "7.68.0")  
-- Found GSL: /usr/include (found version "2.5") 
CMake Error at cmake_modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find JPEG (missing: JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake_modules/FindJPEG.cmake:18 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:300 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/Projects/build/indi-core/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/Projects/build/indi-core/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
ubuntu@ubuntu:
```

Comment: Did you install the listed prerequisites - in particular `libjpeg-dev`? Also it's a bad idea to run `git clone` and `cmake` with `sudo` as that will result in root-owned files in your user's home directory.

Comment: cmake literally tells you what is missing. Install the missing pieces and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Also notice that indi version 1.8.2 is available as ready-made [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/indi-bin). If you don't absolutely need the latest release, maybe go with that. Try

```
sudo apt install indi-bin
```

**Update:** The indi project also provides a PPA with both the latest stable and nightly (experimental) builds:

https://indilib.org/download.html

Unless you are really familiar with building your own software and you are aware of the consequences of installing binaries directly to your system, you might prefer to install stable packages from that PPA.